# Remove $$hashKey in angular material md-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-material

I have a array objects:

```
timezone = [{ id:1,value: "UTC+12"},
            { id:2,"value": "UTC+13"},
            { id:3,"value": "UTC+14"}]
```

In HTML:

```
<md-select name="timezone" ng-model="$ctrl.time" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
    <md-option ng-repeat="time in $ctrl.timezone track by $index" ng-value="time">{{time.value}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

But when I `console.log($scope.time)` I get

```
{
  $$hashKey:"object:197",
  id: 1,
  value: "UTC+12"
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's a desired behavior. Why would you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @Patrick : That's a behavior of `ngModel`. That has got nothing to do with material. :) It gives you additional functionality that makes your life easier. You can directly use things like `indexOf` to see if this particular model exists in, say array in question.

Comment: @AdityaParab: Alright, didn't know ng-model added attributes. Thanks for clearing it out.

Comment: Because when i use `collection.update({_id: id}, {$set:{timezone: time})` in meteor will error `MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$$hashKey'`.

Comment: You could use `var model = time; delete model[$$hashKey]; collection.update({id: id}, {$set: {timezone: model})` instead.

Comment: I tried but still error :( @Patrick

Comment: Well...what is the error? It's difficult to help considering we can't see your screen.

Comment: Oops, it's `delete model['$$hashKey']`, otherwise it tries to remove the attribute with the name of the value.

Comment: I did it. Remove `name="timezone"`. Thank for all :)